# Use existing Spring Boot dataSource for spring-session-jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-session

In my spring-boot application I have an existing dataSource, which I use for `Hibernate` and/or `JdbcTemplate`.

I am planning to use `spring-session` with `spring-session-jdbc` in the future.

Can the already existing and configured dataSource of the application be used?

If yes, how?

Or do I need to configure an additional dataSource for `spring-session-jdbc`?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. But you should edit your question do you mean how to configure spring-session or do you want to know if you can use your custom schema...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is:

Yes, it is possible, like the documentation of the newly released Spring Session 1.2.0 states:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc-boot.html#httpsession-jdbc-boot-configuration

It also works without `Spring Boot`. In an *old* Spring-MVC project based on xml-config, which does not use `Spring Boot`, the configured `dataSource` is automatically used by `Spring Session`.